# Passing parameters between runbooks in Azure Automation

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I'm calling another runbook using the following code:

```
$parameters = @{"Table" = 'myTable'}

Start-AutomationRunbook `
    -Name "ChildRunBook" `
    -Parameters $parameters
```

the reason I'm using `Start-AutomationRunBook' is that this is in a loop and they need to run in parallel, I don't care about the result.

The `Parameters` parameter takes in an IDictonary which I have declared first, with one value.

My child runbook has a string parameter called Table defined as:

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
    [string] $Table
)
```

and the value that is being passed in is:

`{"CliXml":"<Objs Version=\"1.1.0.1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04\">\r\n <S>myTable</S>\r\n</Objs>"}`

How do I either:

1. parse this string to get the value or;
2. get the runbook parse the parameter and assign it for me?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us the definition of your child runbook? Normally, the child runbook should be able to accept Table as a simple string containing 'myTable', without the need to do any special parsing.

Comment: @AnatoliBeliaev I've added the parameter declaration of my child runbook

Comment: Thank you. How do you know this is the value you are getting? For the following pair of runbooks:

**Parent**

    `$parameters = @{"Table" = 'myTable'}; Start-AutomationRunbook -Name "Child" -Parameters $parameters`

**Child**

    `param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
        [string] $Table
    )

    $Table.GetType().FullName; $Table`

I'm getting the expected output:

    System.String
    Table

Comment: Found my issue. In my example, for ease of explaining I used the string 'myTable' to show what I'm doing. In reality this is actually a variable. I had missed the surrounding quotes so it was `$parameters = @{"Table" = $tableName}` instead of `$parameters = @{"Table" = '$tableName'}`. Adding the quotes sorted it. Thanks for looking!